# Creating new user/login in sql azure

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Create a new user/login in sql azure with access to read/insert/update on the database items like tables sp,view etc.

This user will not have the permission to drop table/drop procedures.

Please give me an example.

Comment: [Similar / more recent question with later versions of Sql Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19094970)

Answer (score 32):

First connect to the server and switch to the master database. In master create a login and then add a user for that login to the master database.

```
CREATE LOGIN [MyLogin] WITH password='xxxxxxxxx'
GO

CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyLogin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo] 
GO
```

Next connect/switch to the database you want the new user for. Create a user in that database

```
CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyLogin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO


EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'MyUser';
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'MyUser';
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA :: dbo TO MyUser;
GO
```

Answer (score 29):

You can also use the Azure User Management console - AUMC to manage the Logins and Users.

It's an open-source project available on CodePlex [AUMC.codeplex.com](http://AUMC.codeplex.com)

---

**UPDATE**: Since CodePlex has been retired (thanks to @Danny the code was saved), I recreated a repo in [GitHub](https://github.com/FBoucher/azure-user-management-console) and created a release.

This new version uses .NET 4.8

---

> **Project Description**
>
> Azure User Management Console - AUMC is a User
> Graphic Interface (GUI) that manages the users and logins of an Azure
> SQL database.  The tool is simply converting your action into T-SQL
> commands and executing them on the Azure SQL Database.

A quick simple tool with a user interface!

[image]

Enjoy!

Comment: freaking awesome tool. Totally helps you understand how sql server login/user/role works too

Comment: Codeplex has since been retired.  I have created a new Github repository and moved it across.  https://github.com/miyagisan221b/Azure-User-Management-Console---AUMC

Comment: @Danny would be super awesome if you get the chance to do a release into a zip in github so we dont have to build it :)

Comment: @dalcam, I did it there is a release here https://github.com/FBoucher/azure-user-management-console

Answer (score 4):

please read this article from Microsoft on how to properly create logins, users and assigning access rights in SQL Azure: [Managing Databases and Logins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336235.aspx)

Then, in order to assign or deny specific permissions, review this article from Microsoft as well: [Granting Access to a Database Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365327.aspx)

And here is the link to specifically deny access to permissions: [Deny Object Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173724.aspx)

Note that you can also apply permissions to schemas. A schema is a container of database objects on which you can assign permissions. So you could easily place all your stored procedures in a single schema that you created to that effect, deny alter/drop permission, and grant execute on the schema directly. This way, all the objects within that schema will inherit the permissions defined. Here is the article for schema permissions: [GRANT Schema Permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can do it manually by assigning proper user roles. Check out article: [How to create custom user login for Azure SQL Database](http://kitsula.com/Article/How-to-create-custom-user-login-for-Azure-SQL-Database)

Comment: This was a great concise solution for me as I was used to the GUI way via SSMS/SSDT.

Answer (score 0):

Some Azure sql administration tips can be found here

http://thetechnologychronicle.blogspot.in/2013/11/azure-sql-administration-useful-commands.html

http://thetechnologychronicle.blogspot.in/2013/11/securing-windows-azure-sql-using.html