# How do I create a new user in a SQL Azure database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to use the following template:

```
-- =================================================
-- Create User as DBO template for SQL Azure Database
-- =================================================
-- For login <login_name, sysname, login_name>, create a user in the database
CREATE USER <user_name, sysname, user_name>
    FOR LOGIN <login_name, sysname, login_name>
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = <default_schema, sysname, dbo>
GO

-- Add user to the database owner role
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'<user_name, sysname, user_name>'
GO
```

I would like to create a user called user1 with a password of 'user1pass'. I connected with my default database 'authentication' and I have a query window open.

But the template does not make sense for me. For example what's sysname, where do I supply the password and what should I use as the default_schema?

The particular user needs to have the power to do everything. But how do I set it up so he can do everything, is that done if I make the user a database owner?

So far I have tried:

```
CREATE USER user1, sysname, user1
    FOR LOGIN user1, sysname, user1
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo, sysname, dbo
GO
```

Giving:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ','.

and:

```
CREATE USER user1
    FOR LOGIN user1
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
```

Giving:

> Msg 15007, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 'user1' i

s not a valid login or you do not have permission.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating new user/login in sql azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058058/creating-new-user-login-in-sql-azure)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check out this link for all of the information : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/adding-users-to-your-sql-azure-database/

First you need to create a login for SQL Azure, its syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE LOGIN username WITH password='password';
```

This command needs to run in master db.  Only afterwards can you run commands to create a user in the database.  The way SQL Azure or SQL Server works is that there is a login created first at the server level and then it is mapped to a user in every database.

HTH

Comment: So first time I should say "use master" then create the login, then say "use authentication" ?   Also how can I connect as a different user when in the query window so I can try things out?

Comment: There is no way to switch databases after switching from master to another db in SQL Azure.  Right-click on the query window and click on "Connection->Change Connection" - this will allow you to reconnect with different credentials, once you've created a user

Comment: I'm having some difficulties to get this working on the latest SQL Azure server (V12). Any clues?

Comment: The post gives a really clear, and easy to follow example:
http://kitsula.com/Article/How-to-create-custom-user-login-for-Azure-SQL-Database

Comment: This is misleading. A 'contained user' has no login in master so you can just create a user in the database itself. In fact this approach is recommended because `In a contained database, creating users helps separate the database from the instance of the Database Engine so that the database can easily be moved to another instance of SQL Server. `

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql

Answer (score 148):

**Edit - Contained User (v12 and later)**

As of Sql Azure 12, databases will be created as [Contained Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable) which will allow users to be created directly in your database, without the need for a server login via master.

***Sql (standard) User***

```
CREATE USER [MyUser] WITH PASSWORD = 'Secret';
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]; -- or sp_addrolemember
```

***[AAD linked User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#azure_active_directory_principal)***

```
CREATE USER [SomeUser@mydomain.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader' , N'SomeUser@mydomain.com'
```

***AAD linked Group***

```
CREATE USER [SomeGroup] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader' , N'SomeGroup'
```

**NB!** when connecting to the database when using a contained user that you must always specify the database in the connection string.

[image: Connecting via a contained User]

**Traditional Server Login - Database User (Pre v 12)**

Just to add to @Igorek's answer, you can do the following in Sql Server Management Studio:

**Create the new Login on the server**
In `master` (via the `Available databases` drop down in SSMS - this is because `USE master` doesn't work in Azure):

[image]

create the login:

```
CREATE LOGIN username WITH password=N'password';
```

**Create the new User in the database**
Switch to the actual database (again via the available databases drop down, or a new connection)

```
CREATE USER username FROM LOGIN username;
```

(I've assumed that you want the user and logins to tie up as `username`, but change if this isn't the case.)

**Now add the user to the relevant security roles**

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'username'
GO
```

(Obviously an app user should have less privileges than `dbo`.)

Comment: This answer seems out of date, the user can be created directly in the database instance itself, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql

Comment: You are right - Since 12 there's now Contained Users which don't need the `CREATE LOGIN` step. I've updated.

Answer (score 41):

I followed the answers here but when I tried to connect with my new user, I got an error message stating `"The server principal 'newuser' is not able to access the database 'master' under the current security context"`.

I had to also create a new user in the master table to successfully log in with SSMS.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [newuser] WITH PASSWORD=N'blahpw'
GO
CREATE USER [newuser] FOR LOGIN [newuser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

USE [MyDatabase]
CREATE USER newuser FOR LOGIN newuser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'newuser'
GO
```

Comment: This appears to be the best answer that I could find. It appears to work without a flaw and it is a simple, direct answer.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. Unlike in the past where logins where created in master and then users were created in the actual database, lately I see i have to create a user in the master as well to get it to work as expected!

Answer (score 13):

You can simply create a contained user in SQL DB V12.

```
Create user containeduser with password = 'Password'
```

Contained user login is more efficient than login to the database using the login created by master. You can find more details @ http://www.sqlindepth.com/contained-users-in-sql-azure-db-v12/

Comment: This requires a contained database which has some constraints

Comment: On SQL Azure ALL databases support this feature. In fact it can't be disabled.

Comment: This is the best answer IMO. Short and concise and it just works.

Comment: best answer but anyway Azure SQL sucks

Comment: "As Microsoft evolves the SQL Database service and moves towards higher guaranteed SLAs you may be required to switch to the contained database user model and database-scoped firewall rules to attain the higher availability SLA and higher max login rates for a given database. Microsoft encourages you to consider such changes today." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable

Answer (score 9):

I use the [Azure Management console tool](http://aumc.codeplex.com/) of CodePlex, with a very useful GUI, try it. You can save type some code.

Comment: I would definitely recommend this utility. Since `CodePlex` is shutting down. Mirror download location - https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amber-heat-4041.appspot.com/o/Files%20Publicly%20Shared%2F2017%2FApril%2FAUMC_Setup.msi?alt=media&token=facd5c90-777e-4f19-8f1e-382078c2de25

Answer (score 3):

1 Create login while connecting to the master db
(in your databaseclient open a connection to the master db)

`CREATE LOGIN 'testUserLogin' WITH password='1231!#ASDF!a';`

2 Create a user while connecting to your db (in your db client open a connection to your database)

`CREATE USER testUserLoginFROM LOGIN testUserLogin;`
Please, note, user name is the same as login. It did not work for me when I had a different username and login.

3 Add required permissions

`EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datawriter, 'testUser';`
You may want to add 'db_datareader' as well.

list of the roles:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15

I was inspired by [@nthpixel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/834186/nthpixel) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35786167/1839360), but it did not work for my db client [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).
It did not allow me to run `USE [master]` and `use [my-db]` statements.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/adding-users-to-your-sql-azure-database/

#### How to test your user?

Run the query bellow in the master database connection.

```
SELECT A.name as userName, B.name as login, B.Type_desc, default_database_name, B.*
FROM sys.sysusers A
    FULL OUTER JOIN sys.sql_logins B
       ON A.sid = B.sid
WHERE islogin = 1 and A.sid is not null
```

[List of all users in Azure SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293095/list-of-all-users-in-azure-sql)

Answer (score 2):

create a user and then add user to a specific role:

```
CREATE USER [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'<strong password>'
go
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [test]
go
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question already has an accepted answer which is identical to yours. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link very helpful:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/

It details things like:
 - Azure SQL Database subscriber account
 - Using Azure Active Directory users to access the database
 - Server-level principal accounts (unrestricted access)
 - Adding users to the `dbmanager` database role

I used this and Stuart's answer to do the following:
On the `master` database (see link as to who has permissions on this):

```
CREATE LOGIN [MyAdmin] with password='ReallySecurePassword'
```

And then on the database in question:

```
CREATE USER [MyAdmin] FROM LOGIN [MyAdmin]
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [MyAdmin]
```

You can also create users like this, according to the link:

```
CREATE USER [mike@contoso.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the templates use the following notation:  variable name, variable type, default value.

Sysname is a built-in data type which can hold the names of system objects.

It is limited to 128 Unicode character.

```
-- same as sysname type
declare @my_sysname nvarchar(128);
```

Comment: Thanks but given what you say then how would I create the user and password. I don't see a way to set the password.