# How to create another sa in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm a newbie on SQL, I'd like to know how to create an extra account for Azure Sql Server that has all the permission granted.

It would be great if you could provide the SQL script.

Comment: Please see the [Creating new user/login in sql azure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6058058/4275342). I hope this will help

Comment: Hi @MegaTron, I've tried to create both the login and user, as well as grant all permission using AUMC, but still no select permission.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to use [Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/). When setting your Active Directory admin in the portal, choose an AD group. This way, any user who is a member of this group will have full administrator privileges.